# It's [current year] already, folks, go home

Tags: code-golf, date

On most [new-years](/questions/tagged/new-years) challenges when it is currently not the corresponding year of the challenge, It says this in the front.

> It's [current year] already, folks, go home.

You have to output this text with the current year substituted.

---

## I/O

**Input:** None.

**Output**: `It's [current year] already, folks, go home.`

Comment: First test run, got the time instead of the date: It's 8:58 already, folks, go home.

Comment: Can I take input and then ignore it (i.e do something along the lines of `String goHome(Object foo){return "It's "+currentYear()+" already, folks, go home.";}` (but much shorter, of course))?

Comment: It's a shame I shouldn't compile the challenge to literally: ///, 46 bytes `It's the current year already, folks, go home.`

Comment: @steenbergh If only school was that way in the morning. xD :P

Comment: I feel this challenge would be more appropriate if it were "if it's not the current year, output this, else output nothing", but still good challenge +1

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that this will be used on years after 2000 or it has to work on whatever year the target machine may support?

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, Year will be after the Epoch (1900 on most languages). I mean, come on. It's 2017.

Comment: @SIGSEGV: let's make this extra clear: I'm talking about after 2000, not after 1900. My language supports 1980-2099, but I can shave some bytes by assuming the year to be always after 2000.

Comment: @MatteoItalia ...No. Please don't assume that.

Comment: would this be [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]?

Comment: @tfbninja I don't think so... It may only change annually, but the output is not constant, and the program does essentially take input (just, from the system and not the user).

Answer (score 18):

## bash + date, 40 bytes

```bash
date +"It's %Y already, folks, go home."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SWJKqoK3kWaJerKAaqZCYU5SamFKpo5CWn5NdrKOQnq@QkZ@bqqf0/z8A)

Comment: Also works with ZSH

Comment: It works on nearly every shell, but I named it bash because TIO link is bash.

Answer (score 17):

## C (gcc), 58 bytes

```
f(){printf("It's%s already, folks, go home.",__DATE__+6);}
```

Comment: Note you need to recompile this once a year to get the correct functionality.

Comment: @RobertFraser To run any C (gcc) answer on this site you run it as `gcc golf.c && ./a.out`. That in this process a binary is formed is irrelevant for code golf. My source code is being judged, not the binary being generated (if that was the case my answer would be x86-64).

Comment: So it's not a C program but a GCC+shell program

Comment: @Elazar No, those are just the instructions to run *any* C (gcc) answer on this site.

Comment: True, but this is not "A C program that will produce the desired output" but "A shell command that will produce the desired output"

Comment: Its also not a `c`-Programm because there is no `main()`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Functions are acceptable answers here on codegolf.

Comment: @Elazar `__DATE__` is standard C, any compiler would work, even in a IDE without a visible shell

Comment: Nitpickers ... @orlp, since `__DATE__[6]` is a space, you can spare one byte: `..."It's%s already, folks, go home.",__DATE__+6);}` (mind the missing space between _It's_ and `%s`).

Comment: My point has nothing to do with standard/nonstandard C. My point is: this is a compile-time (preprocessing time) program, not a C program. The runtime is the C preprocessor + some external execution.

Comment: @YSC What??? Somebody removed that golf from my answer. It was in the original version.

Comment: Well, "_somebody_" is OP ^^ They might have thought it was a typo.

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to *Erik the Outgolfer*

```
žg“It's ÿˆ§,¹Ò,‚œ€¨.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ASUA2v//xb5n4oCcSXQncyDDv8uGwqcswrnDkizigJrFk@KCrMKoLv//)

Comment: I think you were confusing 05AB1E with Jelly, which has `“...»` syntax for compressed strings and the `»` can't be suppressed in any case.

Comment: This is the only solution without readable text :(

Comment: Explanation please?

Comment: @ckjbgames built-in dictionary

Comment: @boboquack Yes, `It's ` is readable. For the rest do [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKE0LzM5PyU1JbEkkaugKDOvREM9Jk9dLys/M0@DSwFZWi8vMTdVo0JTrySzJCdVQxMom5ZfpFChkJmnoHR0X/qjhjmeJerFCof3n247tFzn0M7Dk3QeNcw6OvlR05pDK/SUuDQ1//8HAA).

Answer (score 14):

## TeX (44 bytes)

```
It's \the\year\ already, folks, go home.\bye
```

Answer (score 12):

## PHP, 42 bytes

```
It's <?=date(Y)?> already, folks, go home.
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need quotes around the `Y`.

Comment: @MichealJohnson PHP will convert unrecogized constants to strings with the same value, so this should work (but it'll throw a notice)

Comment: @MichealJohnson You're never sure with PHP

Answer (score 8):

## Bash, 45 characters

```bash
printf "It's %(%Y)T already, folks, go home."
```

Bash's built-in `printf` in version 4.2 got the `%(fmt)T` format specifier and since version 4.3 it defaults to current timestamp in absence of argument.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ printf "It's %(%Y)T already, folks, go home."
It's 2017 already, folks, go home.
```

Answer (score 6):

### Batch, 45 bytes

```
@echo It's %date:~6% already, folks, go home.
```

Batch is actually reasonably competitive for once.

Comment: I guess this solution result varies from different locale settings...

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, 53 bytes

```
Print["It's ",Now[[1,1]]," already, folks, go home."]
```

Comment: Reads like "It's Now already, folks, go home."

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
import time
print"It's",time.gmtime()[0],"already, folks, go home."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@ZW5BfVKJQkpmbylVQlJlXouRZol6spAMS0EvPBVEamtEGsTpKiTlFqYkplToKafk52cU6Cun5Chn5QEVK//8DAA)

Answer (score 5):

## x86 machine code on DOS - 62 bytes

```
00000000  b4 04 cd 1a bf 23 01 88  c8 24 0f 00 05 4f c1 e9  |.....#...$...O..|
00000010  04 75 f4 ba 1b 01 b4 09  cd 21 c3 49 74 27 73 20  |.u.......!.It's |
00000020  30 30 30 30 20 61 6c 72  65 61 64 79 2c 20 66 6f  |0000 already, fo|
00000030  6c 6b 73 2c 20 67 6f 20  68 6f 6d 65 2e 24        |lks, go home.$|
0000003e
```

Even though the input from the BIOS is in BCD (as opposed to the plain 16 bit value got from the equivalent DOS call), decoding it to ASCII turned out to be almost as long as base-10 printing a register. Oh well.

```
    org 100h

section .text

start:
    mov ah,4
    int 1ah             ; get the date from BIOS; cx now contains the year in packed BCD
    mov di,placeholder  ; put di on the last character of placeholder
lop:
    mov al,cl
    and al,0xf  ; get the low nibble of cx
    add [di],al ; add it to the digit
    dec di      ; previous character
    shr cx,4    ; next nibble
    jnz lop     ; loop as long as we have digits to unpack in cx
    mov dx,its
    mov ah,9
    int 21h     ; print the whole string
    ret

its:
    db "It's 000"
placeholder:
    db "0 already, folks, go home.$"
```

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, 52 bytes

```
puts"It's #{Time.now.year} already, folks, go home."
```

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 38 bytes

```
"It's "et0=" already, folks, go home."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6/kWaJerKCUWmJgq6SQmFOUmphSqaOQlp@TXayjkJ6vkJGfm6qn9P8/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 58 bytes

```
"It's "<>ToString@#<>" already, folks, go home."&@@Date[]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes no input and returns a string as output. No, I'm not going to make a REPL submission, post it yourself if that one byte is so important.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>53</s>  51 bytes

```perl6
say "It's {Date.today.year} already, folks, go home."
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@1@cWKmg5FmiXqxQ7ZJYkqpXkp@SWKlXmZpYVKuQmFOUmphSqaOQlp@TXayjkJ6vkJGfm6qn9P8/AA)

```perl6
say "It's {now.Date.year} already, folks, go home."
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@1@cWKmg5FmiXqxQnZdfrueSWJKqV5maWFSrkJhTlJqYUqmjkJafk12so5Cer5CRn5uqp/T/PwA)

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE with OS 5.2+), 64 bytes

```
getDate
"It's "+toString(Ans(1))+" already, folks, go home.
```

TI-Basic is a tokenized language. Some commands (`getDate`, `toString(`, etc.), and all lowercase letters are two-bytes and everything else used here is one byte each.

Explanation:

```
getDate                                             # 3, store {Y,M,D} in Ans
"It's "+toString(Ans(1))+" already, folks, go home. # 61, implicitly return required string with Y from getDate
```

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE with OS 5.1), 108 bytes

```
{0,1→L1
getDate
Ans(1)L1→L2
LinReg(ax+b) Y1
Equ►String(Y1,Str0
sub(Str0,1,length(Str0)-3→Str0
"It's "+Str0+" already, folks, go home.
```

TI-Basic is a tokenized language. The more complicated user variables (`Y1`, `L1`, `L2`, `Str0`), some commands (`LinReg(ax+b` , `getDate`, `sub(`,  `Equ►String(`, `length(`), and all lowercase letters are two-bytes and everything else used here is one byte each.

OS 5.2 added a `toString(` command, which obsolesces about half of this submission, which is based off of [this algorithm](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/number-to-string).

Explanation:

```
{0,1→L1                                  # 8 bytes
getDate                                  # 3 bytes, store {Y,M,D} list in Ans
Ans(1)L1→L2                              # 10 bytes, multiply L1 by the year and store in L2
LinReg(ax+b) Y1                          # 5 bytes, take a linear regression of the points specified by each pair of corresponding coordinates in L1 and L2 and store it in Y1
Equ►String(Y1,Str0                       # 8 bytes, convert Y1 to a string
sub(Str0,1,length(Str0)-3→Str0           # 18 bytes, remove the "X+0" from LinReg
"It's "+Str0+" already, folks, go home.  # 56 bytes, implicitly return the required output
```

Comment: you can inline L_1 in the 5.1 programs. gets rid of a newline, two "L_1" tokens, and a →. 6 bytes saved?

Comment: @striking `LinReg(ax+b)` uses L_1 and L_2, so I have to set them both.

Comment: Save some bytes on the first: use `max(getDate)` instead because the largest number in getDate is always the year.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 56 bytes

```
_=>`It's ${Date().split` `[3]} already, folks, go home.`
```

#### Try it online!

```js
const f = _=>`It's ${Date().split` `[3]} already, folks, go home.`

console.log(f())
```

Comment: +1 Exactly the solution I was about to post. You could also use `substr(11,4)` or `slice(11,15)` instead of the `split`.

Comment: Don't you require more than 56 bytes as part the challenge is to output it?

Comment: @cnorthfield Generally speaking in code golf, a function that returns a value is an acceptable answer unless the question has more specific requirements. Check out [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/52433) and [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11932/52433).

Comment: @powelles Thank you for explaining

Comment: That is true @powelles, but your answer doesn't return anything unless more is added to your golf.

Comment: @Kyle The function returns the string. Functions are acceptable, see the previous links to meta.

Comment: @grgarside I was under the impression that the golf has to be executable as is, and return/display with only the code given - which this answer does not. If this isn't the case, then I'll be on my way. As shown in the runnable code snippet, more is needed to make this actually execute: assigning the function `_=>\`It's ${Date().split\` \`[3]} already, folks, go home.\`` to a variable `const f` and calling that function `f()` in a `console.log`

Comment: Please read [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9032/52433) and [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1503/52433), in addition to the posts linked in my previous comment

Comment: “more is needed to make this actually execute” – @KyleFairns, that is callable, all you have to do is to call it: `(_=>\`It's ${Date().split\` \`[3]} already, folks, go home.\`)()`.

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>62 59</s> 62 bytes

```
cat("It's",format(Sys.time(),"%Y"),"already, folks, go home.")
```

Comment: Using `substr(date(),21,24)` instead of `format(Sys.time(),"%Y")` saves three bytes

Comment: does this works in year `20017`?

Comment: Ahh. Correct. Reverting back. Tnx!!

Comment: Using `substring(date(),21)` also saves 3 bytes and works for years beyond 9999.

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell 3.0, 44 bytes

```
"It's $(date|% y*) already, folks, go home."
```

PowerShell is competing quite well today!

Comment: This will not work in version 2 of PowerShell (the foreach syntax). So you should have a v3+ identifier on here. Cool other wise.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 31 bytes

```
`It's {Ki} alÎ%y, folks, go Êà.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5/gWaJerFDtnVmrkJhzuE@1UkchLT8nu1hHIT1f4XDX4QV6//8DAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>39</s> 27 bytes

```
`It's % ×ġ, ṗḊ, go λ∵.`kðt%
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgSXQncyAlIMOXxKEsIOG5l+G4iiwgZ28gzrviiLUuYGvDsHQlIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Surely golfable?

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 58 bytes

```
()=>"It's "+DateTime.Now.Year+" already, folks, go home.";
```

Anonymous function which returns the required string.

Full program:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<string> f=
        ()=>"It's "+DateTime.Now.Year+" already, folks, go home.";
        
        Console.WriteLine(f());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can save characters by using C# 6 strings: $"It's {DateTime.Now.Year} etc etc".

Comment: `()=>$"It's {DateTime.Now.Year} already, folks, go home.";` 57

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 38 bytes

```
s["It's ".d3" already, folks, go home.
```

[Online interpreter.](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=s%5B%22It%27s+%22.d3%22+already%2C+folks%2C+go+home.)

Comment: Same length: `s["It's ".d3d." y\n9?}7Tè+1°Õh6%Ñ<`  (If you replace `\n` by an actual newline) [link](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5B%22It%27s+%22.d3d.%22+y%5Cn9%3F%7D%027T%C2%90%C3%A8%2B1%C2%B0%C3%95h6%25%C2%86%C2%9E%C3%91%3C&debug=0)

Comment: @KarlKastor How did that work for you?

Comment: Don't quite get the question. I used the [online interpreter](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5B%22It%27s+%22.d3d.%22+y%5Cn9%3F%7D%027T%C2%90%C3%A8%2B1%C2%B0%C3%95h6%25%C2%86%C2%9E%C3%91%3C&debug=0). The algorithm to create pyth's packed ."strings is: `+++\.N++hSzeSzCi-RChSzCMz-hCeSzChSzN`

Comment: @KarlKastor I used that, but it must be something in Chrome, and I highly doubt it's the printable unprintable characters.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>77</s> <s>71</s> <s>67</s> 63 bytes

```js
alert("It's "+Date().split(' ')[3]+" already, folks, go home.")
```

Thanks to @programmer5000 for the spaces!

## JavaScript ES6 <s>66</s> 60 bytes

```js
alert(`It's ${Date().split` `[3]} already, folks, go home.`)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Please golf your answer (remove the spaces around the `+`s!)

Comment: `console.log("It's",new Date().getFullYear(),"already, folks, go home.")` for 71 bytes

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk reverted back to console.log, added brackets to ES6 alert

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 113 bytes

```hs
import Data.Time.Clock
f=do t<-getCurrentTime;putStr$"It's "++(fst.span(>'-').show)t++" already, folks, go home."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FcxBDoMgEADAe1@xISZoUD7Q2oteerYf2FRQIrAE1jR9PW3Pk0x1IVFmmJFRP10wevL0Oi52XAn4NmyGpzNnE/mP13TywrkRD5YFhFKtLaxLwtje5SA7XXZ6d6yUAPTZ4PrpwZI/Sg8bwU6/XtSALsIItn4B) Replace `f` with `main` for a full program.

The function `getCurrentTime` returns a `UTCTime` object which looks something like `"2017-04-02 10:22:29.8550527 UTC"` when converted to a string by `show`. `fst.span(>'-')` takes the leading characters while they are larger than `'-'`, that is the current year. For the next 7972 years `take 4` would work for 8 bytes less, but we want our code to work correctly for ever and ever.

As far as I see build-in functions to get the current year require a `import Data.Time.Calendar`, so extracting the year from the string should be the shortest option.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>57</s> 55 bytes

```
"emoh og ,sklof ,ydaerla@ s'tI"4k,y\4*:*/"&2"*+.f7+k,@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/Xyk1Nz9DIT9dQac4Oyc/TUGnMiUxtSgn0UFEoVi9xFPJJFunMsZEy0pLX0nNSElLWy/NXDtbx@H/fwA)

Thanks to James Holderness for pointing out my mistake with the sysinfo instruction.

`"emoh og ,sklof ,ydaerla@ s'tI"` pushes the sentence to the stack where `4k,` prints the first word. `y` is the sysinfo instruction. When passed 20 (the unprintable in the string), it returns `256*256*(year-1900) + 256*month + day of month`. `\4*:*/"&2"*+.` takes just the year from the value and prints it and`f7+k,` prints the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @JamesHolderness Arghhh, that explains why I've never been able to get sysinfo working. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```
_=>`It's ${new Date().getFullYear()} already, folks, go home`
```

Comment: Syntax error, you have an extra closing `)`.

Comment: Oops, fixed now.

Comment: Uhm… I wrote “extra closing `)`”, not “missing opening `(`”. ;)

Comment: You're right...

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>73</s> 68 bytes

```
import time
print(time.strftime("It's %Y already, folks, go home."))
```

Very basic answer. The "%Y" gets the current year.

*Thanks to @ovs for removing 5 bytes*

Comment: Save 6 bytes with `print(f"It's {time.gmtime()[0]} already, go home")`

Comment: @L3viathan thats too similar to the other Python answer

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 48 bytes

```
?@It's `+right$(_D,4)+@ already, folks, go home.
```

I really should start working on substring...

Explanation:

```
?       PRINT
@ ... ` String literal: 
        - creates a string with all the text from @ to `, 
        - stores it as the first available string var (A$)
        - and injects A$ at the current point in the QBasic translated code.
+       String concatenation
right$  QBasic function to take characters from the right.
_D      QBIC's call to get the system date as dd-mm-yyyy (_d gets the time)
+@ ...  Second string lit (B$). Doesn't need the closing ` because of EOF.
```

Update: Substring saves me 4 bytes:

```
?@It's `+_s_D,-4|+@ already, folks, go home.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 48 bytes

```
"It's #{Time.new.year} already, folks, go home."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@6/kWaJerKBcHZKZm6qXl1quV5maWFSrkJhTlJqYUqmjkJafk12so5Cer5CRD1Sh9P8/AA)

Yes, this is string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 42 bytes

```
'It''s '1&Z'V' already, folks, go home.'&h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@6/uWaKuXqygbqgWpR6mrpCYU5SamFKpo5CWn5NdrKOQnq@QkZ@bqqeulvH//9e8fN3kxOSMVAA)

```
'It''s '                      % Push this string
1&Z'                          % Push current year
V                             % Convert to string
' already, folks, go home.'   % Push this string
&h                            % Concatenate all stack contents horizontally
                              % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), [<s>44</s>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154730/41805) 40 bytes

*4 saved thanks to Uriel by rearranging the structure*

```apl
¯5⌽'already, folks, go home.It''s',1⊃⎕ts
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBIfWmz7q2auemFOUmphSqaOQlp@TXayjkJ6vkJGfm6rnWaKuXqyuY/ioq/lR39SSYgA)

#### Explanation

```apl
'alrea ... It''s', ⍝ "alrea .. It's" concatenated with
1⊃⎕ts              ⍝ the first element in the ⎕ts (contains the year)
¯5⌽                ⍝ rotated 5 times to the right
```

Comment: 40 - `¯5⌽'already, folks, go home.It''s',1⊃⎕ts`

Comment: @Uriel Thanks for me getting the crossed out 44 :D

Answer (score 1):

### IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 54 bytes

Not exactly challenging but here we go anyway...

```
"It's "+@Text(@Year(@Now))+" already, folks, go home."
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>81</s> 78 bytes

```
()->System.out.print("It's "+java.time.Year.now()+" already, folks, go home.")
```

Comment: Don't need the semicolon at the end of a lambda, and either print or printf will be shorter than println.

Answer (score 1):

**VBScript, 53 bytes**

```
msgbox"It's "&year(now())&" already, folks, go home."
```

Comment: You could save 4 bytes by assigning to a variable and 2 more by dropping the parentheses after `now`, giving you `s="It's "&year(now)&" already, folks, go home."` (49 bytes). In fact, you can shave 4 more bytes off by just using `It's <%year(now)%> already, folks, go home.` (45 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

### T-SQL, 66 bytes

```
print concat('It''s ',year(getdate()),' already, folks, go home.')
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 65 bytes

**Edit:** This one should handle years of any size, even though SB (as far as I'm aware) doesn't support any year that isn't 4 characters.

```
?"It's "+LEFT$(DATE$,INSTR(DATE$,"/"))+" already, folks, go home.
```

Comment: Does this works in year `20017`?

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 67 bytes

```
alert("It's "+new Date().getFullYear()+" already, folks, go home.")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/), 34 [bytes](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

```
Ƈƈy”VẠṇ`DðC1}816ṚĊC:@-~ḂC'^D^#8Ụ İ
```

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=%C6%87%C6%88y%E2%80%9DV%E1%BA%A0%E1%B9%87%60D%C3%B0C1%7D816%E1%B9%9A%C4%8AC%3A%40-%7E%E1%B8%82C%27%5ED%5E%238%E1%BB%A4%20%C4%B0&input=&run=false)

---

### How it works

```
Ƈƈy”VẠṇ`DðC1}816ṚĊC:@-~ḂC'^D^#8Ụ İ
Ƈƈy                                # Gets the current year.
Ƈ                                  # Gets the current time as an integer.
 ƈy                                # Takes the integer and gets the current year from it.

   ”VẠṇ`DðC1}816ṚĊC:@-~ḂC'^D^#8Ụ İ # Creates the string.
   ”VẠṇ`DðC1}816ṚĊC:@-~ḂC'^D^#8Ụ   # Pushes on the string "It's¤ð¤already,¤folks,¤go¤home." as an array splitting on the "ð" character where "¤" is a space.
                                   # (space) NOOP that separates commands.
                                 İ # Concatenate the array using the current year.
                                   # Implicitly print to the screen.
```

```html
<div id="noodel" code="Ƈƈy”VẠṇ`DðC1}816ṚĊC:@-~ḂC'^D^#8Ụ İ" input="" cols="40" rows="2"></div>

<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/noodel-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/ppcg.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 48 bytes

```
="It's "&YEAR(NOW())&" already, folks, go home."
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 51 bytes

```
?"It's ";LEFT$(DATE$,4);" already, folks, go home.
```

I don't think it's reasonable to ever expect support for 5 digit years, but if SB gets updated in 10 millennia, then this should work for 1 extra byte:

```
DTREAD OUT Y,,?"It's ";Y;" already, folks, go home.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), <s>39</s> 38 + 1 for (-l flag) <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```
τ"It's "pp" already, folks, go home."p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn///98i5JniXqxglJBgZJCYk5RamJKpY5CWn5OdrGOQnq@QkZ@bqqeUsH////yC0oy8/OK/@vmAAA)

Saved one byte thanks to [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)

```
τ"It's "pp" already, folks, go home."p
τ                 push local datetime on stack
"..."             push the first part of the string
     pp           print both
       "..."      second part of string
            p     print it
```

Comment: @DLosc Nice! I'll update

Answer (score 1):

## SenseTalk, 47 bytes

```
put "It's"&&the year&&"already, folks, go home"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 49 bytes

```factor
now year>> [I It's ${} already, folks, go home.I]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU310GBPP3crhcTk5NTi4vyiYoXkxJzUvJTEIoXMvJLUooL8nMSSVAXrpaUlaboWNw3z8ssVKlMTi-zsFKI9FTxL1IsVVKprFRJzilITUyp1FNLyc7KLdRTS8xUy8nNT9TxjIRoXQCkoDQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
‘It's % ¥Ƙ, ⁶Ẇ, go ⱮŻ.‘kO%
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWN9UfNczwLFEvVlBVOLT02AwdhUeN2x7uatNRSM9XeLRx3dHdekAF2f6qS4qTkouhmmCaAQ)

##### Explanation

```python
‘...‘kO%  # Full program
‘...‘     # Compressed string "It's % already, folks, go home."
     kO%  # Replace the "%" with the current year
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Gawk, <strike>64</strike> 60 bytes

GNU Awk has a [couple of built-in function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) to get current time and date.

```
BEGIN{print"It's "strftime("%Y")" already, folks, go home."}
```

**Edit**

The script can run from a file (`-f`), which saves 4 bytes (thanks **manatwork**).

Comment: Actually that is just 60 bytes. The enclosing single quotes and the escape code for single quote are needed only because the shell. You can put the code in a file max.awk and run it as `gawk -f max.awk`, so becomes clear that only the 60 bytes in the file needs to be counted. (The `-f` command line option is for free, other command line options would be counted.)

Comment: @manatwork I didn't know that `-f` is free. But it's shorter the way you say it, no matter if it was free or not. I am really confused when counting command line options towards the byte count. Is there a rule or a post that talks about which options count and which don't? I couldn't find it on my own.

Comment: Not a great reading, but we used to point freshmen to [On “interactive” answers and other special conditions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions). Generally, is free whatever is strictly necessary to let the interpreter find the code.

Answer (score 0):

## Emacs/Lisp, 70 bytes

```
(concat "It's " (format-time-string "%Y") " already, folks, go home.")
```

Comment: You can reduce your byte count by removing unnecessary spaces.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 59 bytes

Gets the system date

```
print("It's "..os.date('%Y').." already, folks, go home.")
```

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 53 bytes

```
say "It's" left(date(s),4) "already, folks, go home."
```

Comment: Does this work in year `20017`?

Comment: No, it assumes a four-character year.

Answer (score 0):

## [Fourier](https://github.com/beta-decay/Fourier), 101 bytes

```
73a116a39a115a32a~S5do32a97a108a+6a101a-4a+3a121a44aSa102a+9~Aa-3a-1a+8a44aSa103a+8aSa104aAa-2a-8a46a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fourier#NYq5DcAwDMQGEgRElt8yM3gCAumzgVd35CIViePt5phVfAQKnlizPG9wNOzqSA0YmpF4JiNnZkwJGetGHTWk/7MfP5KJmNAolb0/)

Comment: This doesn't have as many `4`s as I expected...

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL 74 bytes

```
print 'It''s '+CAST(year(GETDATE())as varchar)+' already, folks, go home.'
```

Appreciate that there is a shorter answer above but in the event that you're in the SQL-Server dark ages and don't have CONCAT available this will work :)

Answer (score 0):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/) 43 bytes

```
Send,It's %A_Year% already, folks, go home.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl, 63

No chance of ever winning

```
puts "It's [clock f [clock se] -f %Y] already, folks, go home."
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/FQEG51482)

Answer (score 0):

## Forth, 49 bytes

I tried leaving off the trailing `"` and it worked. Cool.

```
." It's " time&date . ." already, folks, go home.
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#@6@npOBZol6soKRQkpmbqpaSWJKqoKcAFE3MKUpNTKnUUUjLz8ku1lFIz1fIyM9N1fv/HwA)

> `time&date` – *nsec nmin nhour nday nmonth nyear*
> Report the current time of day. Seconds, minutes and hours are numbered from 0. Months are numbered from 1. - [Source](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Keeping-track-of-Time.html)

Answer (score 0):

## [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), 65 bytes

```
SELECT"It's "||strftime('%Y','now')||' already, folks, go home.';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sqlite#@x/s6uPqHKLkWaJerKBUU1NcUpRWkpmbqqGuGqmuo56XX66uWVOjrpCYU5SamFKpo5CWn5NdrKOQnq@QkZ@bqqdu/f8/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Processing.org 48 bytes

```
print("It's",year(),"already, folks, go home.");
```

Answer (score 0):

## Jekyll, 35 bytes

Jekyll is a static site generator and it's the backend of GH Pages. *If only* it counts as a language here.

```
It's :year already, folks, go home.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 38 bytes

```
%"It's %d already, folks, go home.".d3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1XJs0S9WEE1RSExpyg1MaVSRyEtPye7WEchPV8hIz83VU9JL8X4/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-language-reference), 56 Bytes

```
MsgBox "It's " & Year(Now) & " already, folks, go home."
```

Comment: Squash the spaces and save 4 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Excel VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-language-reference), 44 Bytes

Not sure if this is a cheat... assuming "It's" in in cell A1 on an Excel worksheet and " already, folks, go home." is in A3:

```
Msgbox Range("A1") & Year(Now) & Range("A3")
```

Comment: Well, this is .

Comment: @user202729 I don't see any technical reason why (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info). This function takes no inputs as per OPs rules. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

**VBA (Excel), 42 bytes**

Using Immediate Window.

`?"It's"year(now)"already, folks, go home."`

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 47 bytes

```
C!DateFormat!"It's %Y already, folks, go home."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@99Z0SWxJNUtvyg3sURRybNEvVhBNVIhMacoNTGlUkchLT8nu1hHIT1fISM/N1VP6X9AUWZeSXRadGzsfwA)

This is a constant function that returns the year it was defined in. Alternatively, a function that returns the year it was called in:

```
{DateFormat!"It's %Y already, folks, go home."}
```

And for an extra byte:

```
"It's %s already, folks, go home."%Date[].year|C
```

or

```
{"It's %s already, folks, go home."%Date[].year}
```

Nothing too special going on here in either case.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <strike>90</strike> <strike>86</strike> <strike>83</strike> 78 bytes

```
from datetime import*;print"It's",date.today().year,"already, folks, go home."
```

EDIT: Shaved off a couple of bytes.

EDIT: Shaved off more thanks to @HyperNeutrino

Comment: I can't believe ST beat Python 2...

Comment: Not valid. You need to print the "It's ___ already, folks, go home" part.

Comment: D'oh sorry... fixed...

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fck7DoAgDADQqzQsfkIYXD2Bx2hCFSJQUrr09Bjf@rpp4nbMeQtXiKikuRLk2ll0P7vkpu7SZTj/Z1COaOsWjFC8wyKE0TzcXN7h4WFIXCm4OT8)

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), <s>24</s> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
uS"³9n⁶=⅛8!⅔ηεēæ▼∙Ω╝‘⁽
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=dVMlMjIlQjM5biV1MjA3NiUzRCV1MjE1QjglMjEldTIxNTQldTAzQjcldTAzQjUldTAxMTMlRTYldTI1QkMldTIyMTkldTAzQTkldTI1NUQldTIwMTgldTIwN0Q_,v=0.12)

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 52 characters

(48 characters code + 4 characters command line options)

```
now|strftime("It's %Y already, folks, go home.")
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -nr 'now|strftime("It'"'"'s %Y already, folks, go home.")'
It's 2018 already, folks, go home.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8vv7ymuKQorSQzN1VDybNEvVhBNVIhMacoNTGlUkchLT8nu1hHIT1fISM/N1VPSfP//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3Xz/usWAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 63 characters

```
\A=@subst{<D4>=It's \$0 already, folks, go home.\;?=;@date}@end
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '\A=@subst{<D4>=It'"'"'s \$0 already, folks, go home.\;?=;@date}@end'
It's 2018 already, folks, go home.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [jamal](http://peter.verhas.com/progs/perl/jamal/), 56 characters

```
{@format date=YEAR}It's {@date} already, folks, go home.
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ perl jamal.pl year.jam 
It's 2018 already, folks, go home.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 47 bytes

```arturo
clip~"It's |now\year| already, folks, go home."
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?RWv6k4)

Outputs to clipboard. The link includes a stdout version too.