# Recover the power from the prime power

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, primes

It seems that many people would like to have this, so it's now a sequel to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167106/recover-the-prime-from-the-prime-power)!

**Definition**: a *prime power* is a natural number that can be expressed in the form p<sup>n</sup> where p is a prime and n is a natural number.

**Task**: Given a prime power p<sup>n</sup> > 1, return the power n.

**Testcases**:

```
input output
9     2
16    4
343   3
2687  1
59049 10
```

**Scoring**: This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: **Note**: This challenge might be trivial in some golfing languages, but it's not so trivial for some mainstream languages, as well as the language of June 2018, QBasic.

Comment: Can we output True instead of 1? Alternatively, float instead of ints?

Comment: @JoKing yes, yes.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer [Challenge accepted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167279/16766) :D

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=2:i/n or(n%i<1)+f(n,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYpBCsIwFAX3nuJthIQGa1KpWuxJxEXVFj80P@EnXfT0MQOzGSbu@RfYFfIxSEba06F6SnOW@bNJosArecrKniu6LOM6@fd3Ahsa3UAtI4jiIz2sbhZVa2PrFQQMYjydwd3A9gbdpTNw/e36GhCFOKPuuvwB)

Counts factors. Apparently I wrote the [same golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64948/20260) in 2015.

Narrowly beats out the non-recursive

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes**

```python
lambda n:sum(n%i<1for i in range(1,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCoMwFAXAq7yNkMDfJEpaRU/Suoi0qQF9SrQLTx/JLGe/znmjzWF458Wv08eD3fFfFavYm7AlREQief6@ygi1ziVZ8mUFrcA4Qd3UAuuej7HDniJPBEWdbw)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
Òg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8KT0//9NLQ1MLAE)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome indeed! For anyone reading this: [`Ò`: Push list of prime factors (with duplicates)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/info.txt#L261) and [`g`: Push length](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/info.txt#L105).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x=2:n%x and f(n,x+1)or n/x<2or-~f(n/x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYtBDoIwFAX3nOJtTNpYBQqiEDmJcVEFYhP4Je03KRuvjn3JLGaSt278cVTtdlmdZ4QtZIlzGNmP768P1tFsF8uiLNLkPvWzWV6DAanY644OEYYGTCL5sZTOg/J4186ffqnlMT1SY1jCo1UoG4WqrhR0c7sqXNqibp9dBqzeEotJsJT7Hw)

Outputs `True` instead of 1 ([as allowed by OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167199/recover-the-power-from-the-prime-power#comment404175_167199)). Recursive function that repeatedly finds the lowest factor and then calls the function again with the next lowest power until it reaches 1. This is an extension of [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167125/76162) to the previous question.

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 22

- 2 bytes saved thanks to @H.PWiz and @Cowsquack

```bash
factor|tr -cd \ |wc -c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYpBCsIwEEX3c4pP0WVBba2GgifpJs5MSUEaSQa6yd1jEcS/erz3nz6HuoXlpUjqBabZ2GcdIZGw752W1WY0R0H7QIPD7/GtyiH@FQqmOnu2mIoltCyYUDbeqUpctTo6D9T1HV2G@42u7tQ7@gA)

Comment: Does `factor|sed s/\ //|wc -w` work?

Comment: What about `factor|tr -cd \ |wc -c`?

Comment: Turns out awk is indeed shorter, `factor|awk \$0=NF-1`

Answer (score 5):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), \$\require{cancel}\xcancel 4 3\$ bytes

```
|f%
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7Cf%25&i=9%0A16%0A343%0A2687%0A59049&a=1&m=2)

Length of prime factorization.

Comment: Ahh.. you're breaking the [crossed out 4 is still regular 4 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154730/52210) meme. ;p (It was getting old anyway though.. So well done I guess)

Comment: \$\text{Yay, MathJax abuse!}\$ But remember to put the cross before the actual bytecount otherwiae the leaderboard snippet may not be able to recognize it.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](http://cran.r-project.org) 22 bytes

Power `n` is the number of multiples of `p` in `p^n` when `p` is prime:

```
sum(!(b<-scan())%%2:b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0V0NRI8lGtzg5MU9DU1NV1cgqSfO/5X8A)

Answer (score 5):

### [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles) 5 bytes

```
,|`,$~^%@
```

This is 9 nibbles each of which is encoded in a half byte in the binary form. I think this is the shortest solution that doesn't use built in factoring.

Translation:

```
,      length
 |     filter
  `,$  0..input
  ~    not \x->
   ^   pow (so that 0 which would have been 0 from the mod isn't)
    %  mod
     @ input
     implicit $ (x)
    implicit $ (x)
```

It works by just counting the number of numbers the input divides evenly

You could run it passing in a list of numbers to process in stdin or as a command line arg. Nibbles isn't on TIO.run yet...

Answer (score 4):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>50</s> 41 bytes

```
1si[dli1+dsi%0<X]dsXx[dli/dli<Y]sYdli<Yzp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2j@37A4MzolJ9NQO6U4U9XAJiI2pTiiAiSiD8Q2kbHFkWC6quD/fwA)

Takes input from the top of the stack (in TIO, put the input in the header to load it onto the stack before execution). Outputs to stdout.

## Explanation

**Registers used:**

`i`: the current trial divisor, while `X` is running. Later, the divisor we've found.

`X`: the macro `dli1+dsi%0<X`, which has the effect "increment `i`, then check the modulus with the value on the stack (which will be the original input). If it's not zero, repeat".

`Y`: the macro `dli/dli<Y`, which has the effect "Add to the stack a copy of the current top of the stack, divided by `i`. Repeat until `i` is reached."

Full program:

```
1si                 Initialize i
[dli1+dsi%0<X]dsXx  Define and run X
[dli/dli<Y]sY       Define Y
dli<Y               Run Y, but only if needed (if the input wasn't just i)
z                   The stack is i^n, i^(n-1), ... ,i, so print the stack depth
```

Comment: I found a much better solution! Editing now...

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 2

Count prime factors:

```
lP
```

[Online test](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lP&input=59049&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=9%0A16%0A343%0A2687%0A59049&debug=0).

Answer (score 4):

## [face](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/face), 86 bytes

```
(%d@)\$*,c'$,io>Av"[""mN*c?*m1*mp*m%*s1"$pN1p:~+p1p%%Np?%~:=/NNp+?1?-%N1?%=p%'$i?w1'%>
```

Hooray, longer than Java!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoNADAXQuwzzmTZaakAXCpr2ArlAu5GpgovBgNDuvHr63jrnxf2Cz@P6jlTnFOttn57f8AqhKGWhwlSMCujgEE3ZhrMyNkBNcA7jXdUqYblBWTAaUtzkxwmTu3d90/Z/)

I am particularly fond of the trick of using the return value of `sscanf`.
Normally the return value would be discarded,
but here it will always be 1,
because we're always reading a single number as input.
We can take advantage of this
by assigning its return value to the variable `1`,
saving the 2 bytes that would otherwise be required
to assign `1` to 1 explicitly.

```
(%d@)

\$*,c'$,io>  ( setup - assign $ to "%d", * to a number, o to stdout )
Av"[""mN*    ( set " to input and allocate space for N for int conversion )
c?*          ( calloc ?, starting it at zero - this will be the output )
m1*          ( allocate variable "1", which gets the value 1 eventually )
mp*m%*       ( p is the prime, % will be used to store N mod p )

s1"$pN       ( scan " into N with $ as format; also assigns 1 to 1 )

1p:~         ( begin loop, starting p at 1 )
  +p1p       ( increment p )
  %%Np       ( set % to N mod p )
?%~          ( repeat if the result is nonzero, so that we reach the factor )

:=           ( another loop to repeatedly divide N by p )
  /NNp       ( divide N by p in-place )
  +?1?       ( increment the counter )
  -%N1       ( reuse % as a temp variable to store N-1 )
?%=          ( repeat while N-1 is not 0 -- i.e. break when N = 1 )

p%'$i?       ( sprintf ? into ', reusing the input format string )
w1'%>        ( write to stdout )
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache) and [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/) polyglot, 10 bytes

```
PrimeOmega
```

[Try Attache online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBlq/A/oCgzN9U/NzU98b9fampKcbRKQUFyeiwXUDyvJCS1uMQ5sTi1ODpNRyHaUkfB0ExHwdjEWEfByMzCXEfB1NLAxDI29j8A) [Try Mathematica online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/A/oCgzN9U/NzU9EcTMK4n2TSyITtNRqLbUUTA001EwNjHWUTAyszDXUTC1NDCxrI2N/Q8A)

Simply a builtin for computing the number of prime factors **N** has.

### Explanation

Since **N** = **p**<sup>*k*</sup>, Ω(**N**) = Ω(**p**<sup>*k*</sup>) = *k*, the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

## Whitespace, 141 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_number][T    T   T   _Retrieve][S S S T  N
_Push_1][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP_1][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate][S T   S S T   S N
_Copy_2nd_input][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][T    S T T   _Modulo][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_BREAK_1][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP_1][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_BREAK_1][S S S N
_Push_0][S T    S S T   S N
_Copy_2nd_input][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_LOOP_2][S N
S _Duplicate_input][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_BREAK_2][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S T  S S T   S N
Copy_2nd_factor][T  S T S _Integer_divide][N
S N
T   N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP_2][N
S S S S N
_Create_Label_BREAK_2][S N
N
_Discard_top][T N
S T _Print_as_number]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TYxLCoAwEEPXySnmDvVCIgXdCQoef5p0urAfyGRe8p3X2597P3pmRFAXhI8mkLYsPFrCT5T2mK4QGov6tTfI6VS08o79yrBgrMbZYiUZyGxbGw) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer n = STDIN as input
Integer f = 1
Start LOOP_1:
  f = f + 1
  if(n modulo-f == 0)
    Call function BREAK_1
  Go to next iteration of LOOP_1

function BREAK_1:
  Integer r = 0
  Start LOOP_2:
    if(n == 1)
      Call function BREAK_2
    r = r + 1
    n = n integer-divided by f
    Go to next iteration of LOOP_2

function BREAK_2:
  Print r as number to STDOUT
  Program stops with an error: Exit not defined
```

**Example run: [`input = 9`](https://tio.run/##TYxLCoBADEPXySl6DY8jMjDuBAWPX5N2Fs4H0vQl7zyfcV/7MTIjgrogfDSBtGXh0RJ@orRHuUJoLPr33iDL6WjnHfuVYcFYjdViJRnI3D4)**

```
Command    Explanation                    Stack           Heap    STDIN   STDOUT   STDERR

SSSN       Push 0                         [0]
SNS        Duplicate top (0)              [0,0]
TNTT       Read STDIN as number           [0]             {0:9}   9
TTT        Retrieve                       [9]             {0:9}
SSSTN      Push 1                         [9,1]           {0:9}
NSSN       Create Label_LOOP_1            [9,1]           {0:9}
 SSSTN     Push 1                         [9,1,1]         {0:9}
 TSSS      Add top two (1+1)              [9,2]           {0:9}
 SNS       Duplicate top (2)              [9,2,2]         {0:9}
 STSSTSN   Copy 2nd from top              [9,2,2,9]       {0:9}
 SNT       Swap top two                   [9,2,9,2]       {0:9}
 TSTT      Modulo top two (9%2)           [9,2,1]         {0:9}
 NTSSN     If 0: Jump to Label_BREAK_1    [9,2]           {0:9}
 NSNN      Jump to Label_LOOP_1           [9,2]           {0:9}

 SSSTN     Push 1                         [9,2,1]         {0:9}
 TSSS      Add top two (2+1)              [9,3]           {0:9}
 SNS       Duplicate top (3)              [9,3,3]         {0:9}
 STSSTSN   Copy 2nd                       [9,3,3,9]       {0:9}
 SNT       Swap top two                   [9,3,9,3]       {0:9}
 TSTT      Modulo top two (9%3)           [9,3,0]         {0:9}
 NTSSN     If 0: Jump to Label_BREAK_1    [9,3]           {0:9}
NSSSN      Create Label_BREAK_1           [9,3]           {0:9}
SSSN       Push 0                         [9,3,0]         {0:9}
STSSTSN    Copy 2nd from top              [9,3,0,9]       {0:9}
NSSTN      Create Label_LOOP_2            [9,3,0,9]       {0:9}
 SNS       Duplicate top (9)              [9,3,0,9,9]     {0:9}
 SSSTN     Push 1                         [9,3,0,9,9,1]   {0:9}
 TSST      Subtract top two (9-1)         [9,3,0,9,8]     {0:9}
 NTSSSN    If 0: Jump to Label_BREAK_2    [9,3,0,9]       {0:9}
 SNT       Swap top two                   [9,3,9,0]       {0:9}
 SSSTN     Push 1                         [9,3,9,0,1]     {0:9}
 TSSS      Add top two (0+1)              [9,3,9,1]       {0:9}
 SNT       Swap top two                   [9,3,1,9]       {0:9}
 STSSTSN   Copy 2nd from top              [9,3,1,9,3]     {0:9}
 TSTS      Integer-divide top two (9/3)   [9,3,1,3]       {0:9}
 NSNTN     Jump to Label_LOOP_2           [9,3,1,3]       {0:9}

 SNS       Duplicate top (3)              [9,3,1,3,3]     {0:9}
 SSSTN     Push 1                         [9,3,1,3,3,1]   {0:9}
 TSST      Subtract top two (3-1)         [9,3,1,3,2]     {0:9}
 NTSSSN    If 0: Jump to Label_BREAK_2    [9,3,1,3]       {0:9}
 SNT       Swap top two                   [9,3,3,1]       {0:9}
 SSSTN     Push 1                         [9,3,3,1,1]     {0:9}
 TSSS      Add top two (1+1)              [9,3,3,2]       {0:9}
 SNT       Swap top two                   [9,3,2,3]       {0:9}
 STSSTSN   Copy 2nd from top              [9,3,2,3,3]     {0:9}
 TSTS      Integer-divide top two (3/3)   [9,3,2,1]       {0:9}
 NSNTN     Jump to Label_LOOP_2           [9,3,2,1]       {0:9}

 SNS       Duplicate top (1)              [9,3,2,1,1]     {0:9}
 SSSTN     Push 1                         [9,3,2,1,1,1]   {0:9}
 TSST      Subtract top two (1-1)         [9,3,2,1,0]     {0:9}
 NTSSSN    If 0: Jump to Label_BREAK_2    [9,3,2,1]       {0:9}
NSSSSN     Create Label_BREAK_2           [9,3,2,1]       {0:9}
 SNN       Discard top                    [9,3,2]         {0:9}
 TNST      Print as integer               [9,3]           {0:9}           2
                                                                                    error
```

Program stops with an error: No exit found.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
ḋl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7pz//y3/RwEA)

#### Explanation

```
ḋ        Prime decomposition
 l       Length
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>8</s> 2 bytes

```apl
≢⍭
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R24RHnYse9a4FshUsudIUDM2AhLGJMZA0MrMwB1KmlgYmlgA)

`⍭` finds factors, `≢` counts how many of them there are.

Answer (score 3):

## QBasic, <s>51</s> 41 bytes

```basic
INPUT n
FOR i=2TO n
f=f-(n/i=n\i)
NEXT
?f
```

-10 bytes by copying the approach from [Darren Smith's Nibbles answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240635/16766): For a prime power input, the desired output equals the number of integers between 1 (exclusive) and the input (inclusive) that evenly divide the input.

```basic
INPUT number
FOR testFactor = 2 TO number
  ' number is divisible by testFactor if their float division equals
  ' their int division
  isDivisible = (number / testFactor = number \ testFactor)
  ' Truthy is -1 in QBasic, so we subtract rather than add to the tally
  numFactors = numFactors - isDivisible
NEXT testFactor
PRINT numFactors
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 42 bytes

```
D,f,@,bUbU$^=
L,dVfbUG$XGRzGGXzÞ{f}bUbU0$:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQScpNClUJc6Wy0cnJSwtKdRdJcI9qMrdPaLq8LzqtFqQrIGK1X@VnMTcpJREBUM7ey7///8NzQA)

I don't even know where to begin explaining this mess.

### Explained

```
D,f,@,bUbU$^=
D,f,@,        ; a helper function f that given a list [number, [x, y]]
      bUbU$^  ;   returns whether x ^ y
            = ;   equals number

L,dVfbUG$XGRzGGXzÞ{f}bUbU0$:
L,                            ; a lambda that
  dV                          ; places its input into the register
    fbU                       ; and gets the prime factor of the input. This is guaranteed to be a single item because the input is a prime raised to a power.
       G$X                    ; push a list of input copies of that power
          GRz                 ; and zip that with the range [1...input]
             GGX              ; also, push input copies of the input
                z             ; and zip that with our big list. I'm calling it a big list because it is what it is.
                 Þ{f}         ; filter that list based on the results of the helper function f
                     bUbU0$:  ; get the power out of the many nested lists returned.
```

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HQcfJTSXOlstHJyUsLSnUXSXCPajK3T2i6vC8dCe3gv8qOYm5SSmJCoZ29lz@//8bmxgDAA). You can replace `f` with `g`, per [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240418/66833) tip to save 2 bytes, use the full flatten command `BF` instead of two unpacks and use some stack manipulation to replace `0$:`

Answer (score 3):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 7 bytes

*(or possibly 6.5 depending on how [this meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24251/16766) shakes out)*

```
+(*'?(*%.(02.
```

[Try it!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=KygqJz8oKiUuKC0yMC4_&a=ODE_)

#### Explanation

```
+(*'?(*%.(
         (0    Inclusive range
           2    from 2
            .   to the argument
     (*        Map over each value x in that list:
       %.       Argument mod x
 (*            Map over each value in that list:
   '?           Logical negation
               The result is a list containing 1 for each number that divides
               the argument, 0 otherwise
+              Take its sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 3 bytes

```
!\?___
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIhXFw_X19fIiwiWzI1Nl0iLDBd)

---

A basically built-in solution for now, working on a non-trivial version (might not be possible given Risky's heavy investment in specific operators, and generally awful control flow).

```
!      Count
 \     Prime factors
  ?    Input
   ___ (Padding)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 1 byte

```
ƒ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FouOTVpSnJRcDOUu2GzJZWjGZWxizGVkZmHOZWppYGIJkQIA)

`ƒ` factorizes the input number, and returns a list of unique prime factors and a list of exponents.

Only the top of the stack will be printed, which is the list of exponents. Since the input is a prime power, this will be a singleton list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
Æḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28Mdvf///ze1NDCxBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 59 bytes

A lambda from `int` to `int`.

```java
x->{int f=1,c=0;while(x%++f>0);for(;x>1;c++)x/=f;return c;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XU7PT4MwFD7DX/EuJiV0FdycYoWjiQdPO5rF1K7FYldIWzYWwt@OnXIyecn73sv3q2Entmo7YZrD99z1n1px4Jo5B29MGRjjaHk6z3xYUhmmoQkq0nuliewN96o15GUBz6/Gi1pYDAuoQEI5D6tqVMaDLHPMy4yev5QWaLhJU1llCZWtRXSocsrTNBluS0mt8L01wOk0RzT@X@PUqgMcQ0O081aZ@n0PzNYuuRaOghmgaxhnTnzAExhxhnAH0lhgyLcY1ps1hrvt4wOG@yLbFNOfMtpdnBdH0vaedMHXa4MkYV2nL@jXLElooE1xmCmefwA)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 4 bytes

```
#@q:
```

`q:` gives the list of prime factors, `#` gives the length of the list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/lR0Krf5rcnGlJmfkK6QpWCoYmikYmxgrGJlZmCuYWhqYWHJx/QcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes

```r
length(numbers::primeFactors(scan()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pyc1L70kQyOvNDcptajYyqqgKDM31S0xuSS/qFijODkxT0NTU/O/oZHFfwA)

Comment: `sum(x|1)` is nearly always shorter than `length(x)`

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
Yfz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzKt6v9/U0sDE0sA)

#### Explanation:

```
     % Implicit input: 59049
Yf   % Factorize input [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
  z  % Number of non-zero elements: 10
     % Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `l`, 1 byte

```
ǐ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=l&code=%C7%90&inputs=9&header=&footer=)

-1 byte thx to @lyxal

Length of the prime factors, the flags are cheaty+awesome

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=l&code=%C7%90&inputs=9&header=&footer=) for 1 byte

Answer (score 2):

## MS Excel, 33 bytes

An anonymous worksheet function that takes input from cell `A1` and outputs to the calling cell

```vb
-SUM(-(MOD(A1,SEQUENCE(A1))<1))-1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
f
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWYmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD01OTA0OSZmbGFncz1M)

Push the prime `f`actors of the input then take the `L`ength of the list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
def f(n,p=2,i=0):
	while n%p:p+=1
	while n>p**i:i+=1
	return i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI0@nwNZIJ9PWQNOKi7M8IzMnVSFPtcCqQNvWEM63K9DSyrTKBAsVpZaUFuUpZP4vKMrMKwEaYGxirPn/PwA)

Nothing fancy here.

Comment: You can save three bytes by making it a full program: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDk6vA1ogr09aAqzwjMydVIU@1wKpA29YQxrUr0NLKtMoEiRQUZeaVaGRq/v9vbGL8HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
k l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P1sh5/9/U0sDE0sA)

### Explanation:

```
k l
k     Get the prime factors of the input
  l   Return the length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
ol
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/z8/5/9/U0sDE0sA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
f n=sum$(0^).mod n<$>[2..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgFAXQrdyBgwKRsugD1UakQChJ0pdkrf91zmnzdYTA7EBz/qIoqq1U8d5Bk1iMVopWjtYTZqTH0wuBaBMcjJYYJepOomkbCd0N/co/)

Counts factors. Compare:

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes**

```hs
f n=sum[1|0<-mod n<$>[2..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFNDkAwEAbQq3yLLodQUiStizRdNEEIMxo/O3ev99Z47/Nx5LxA3P2yr7/KFnxOEKtGr8tSQsgcN4FDujZ5oMAxYYHXhIFQG0LTNgRt@i7kHw)

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes**

```hs
f n=sum[0^mod n i|i<-[2..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgFAXAq7xFS5PSsII8iRgIJUn6k6xdd7eZw5Vzj7FWD9LlTaZb07WBEL6wtEZwTtbW5AJBI9@BHjRILsPDCIaZoVcMcpAMQk2jrT8)

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes**

```hs
f n=sum[1|i<-[2..n],mod n i<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgFAXQrdxBw5eghhXYSsSBUJKkL@kza@92zh7uY8u5tQhe7rc4@SXbOyUEeyrnCkay0rcSEmNBvRI/6FBCRYRThJkgDUEPmqDMNPr2Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 18 bytes

```matlab
@(x)nnz(factor(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzL69KIy0xuSS/CMjR/J@mYWppYGKp@R8A)

Does what it says on the tin: Number of non-zero elements in the prime factorization of the input.

Answer (score 1):

## Cjam, 5 bytes

```
rimf,
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/39TSwMRSQSE3Tef/fwA)

Explanation:

```
ri      take the input and convert it to an int
  mf    factors the input
    ,   take the length of the list
```

Builtins are great!

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 29 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k=n)=>--k&&!(n%k)+f(n,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcnBDkAgGADgu6fIgfWPGLVwyLsYMrI/k3n9zDpx/b5tuAc3nutxMbTT7L1WFHOjEFTPmEnTmGJiINOvgh8tOrvPxW4XqmkHQMqS1NGXKxlc/JwLHoL/opZtE6byDw) Note: Stack overflows for larger inputs.

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 91 bytes

```
let rec d n c v=if v=n then c else d(n/v)(c+1)v
let p n=d n 1(Seq.find(fun x->n%x=0){2..n})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1NC4JAGITv/YpBEFxCU/sUW2/dg47RQXS3FurVtm0xqt9uq81tmJln5COsGi36/ioMtKhQw4JQcSVhOcFchHMQ14dAHdDMsqCaJsxOhn4L4rVrJ8FB3COpqA7kk9CFBfkdj9k7jSL6sv643ZHRr32jyBSncXorFaHUZ8sncDpmOZJVjvliniNdbdY5llm8yE74FBjgygiNPx1h4Z67IWm1I0qC5yv4ykPHRlrc/wA)

`p` gets the prime factor. `d` recursively divides the target value until it's equal to the prime factor and returns the count from that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 19 bytes

port of [Xi'an's answer in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210531/98541)

```julia
n->sum(n.%(2:n).<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZclBCsIwEEDR/ZxiNsIEtDRtrUase48R6AQicVqSFLx9qnYl/uX7jyV4q1/FDUUOt7Q8SaodNRdR1VWr4qaImVNGLxjZjsELJ1KA774@4GxjYrpL3n9gW3P0koPQv7jNflEBy1gMgu4R2q6Fpj@f4Gjqzqw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 30 bytes

```
.+
$*
((?=(1+)(\2+)$)\3)+1
$#1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLS0PD3lbDUFtTI8ZIW1NFM8ZYU9uQS0XZ8P9/SwUuQzMFLmMTYy4jMwtzLlNLAxNLAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
((?=(1+)(\2+)$)\3)+1
```

Repeatedly find the largest factor of the current value. Eventually this becomes 1, which is then matched at the end outside of the loop.

```
$#1
```

Output the resulting number of factors, which for a prime power will be the power.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors`, 18 bytes

```
[ factors length ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVdQlJmbWqyXBpYpVihOLSxNzUtOLVYoKEotKakESueVKFhzcVVzKQCBJYhQUFTQtVMwAgsYmsEFTMACxibGMAFjsICRmYU5VMAQLGBqaWBiCRUw4Kr9H60AszwnNS@9JEMh9n9uYoFCcUlicrbefwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 34 bytes

```
=SUM((MOD(A1,SEQUENCE(A1-1))=0)*1)
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnDHVXUt-TVESVFZ0?e=wadvDN)

Counts the factors.  Works up to 2 ^ 20.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
Lp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/36fg////ppYGJpYA)

#### Explanation

```
Lp
L  length of
 p prime factors
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 7 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
+´0=↕|⊢
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgK8K0MD3ihpV84oqiCgo+4ouI4p+cRsKoIDnigL8xNuKAvzM0M+KAvzI2ODfigL81OTA0OQ==)

Translates directly to Dyalog APL:

```apl
+/0=⍳|⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1vfwPZR7@aaR12L/qc9apvwqLfvUd9UT/9HXc2H1hs/apsI5AUHOQPJEA/P4P8QubYJBlxAKQ2gJp00zUMrFCwVDM0UjE2MFYzMLMwVTC0NTCwB)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 2 bytes

```
ḍl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@GO3pz//y0B)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k=2)=>n%k?n>1&&f(n,k+1):1+f(n/k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTyfb1kjT1i5PNds@z85QTS0NJKRtqGllqA1k6mdr/k/OzyvOz0nVy8lP10jTsFQAAk1NBX19BSMuVClDM7iUCZqUsYkxTMoYTcrIzMIcKmWIJmVqaWBiCZUy@A8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 36 bytes

```perl6
{round .log/log (2..*).first: $_%%*}
```

Looks for the first factor `(2..*).first: $_%%*`, then from there calculates the approximate value (logs won't get it exact) and rounds it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@7@6KL80L0VBLyc/XR@IFTSM9PS0NPXSMouKS6wUVOJVVbVq/xcnghRrGGtpGZprWnNBueZArqmm9X8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 8 bytes

```
bigomega
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D8pMz0/NzU98X9iQUFOpUaegq6dQkFRZl4JkKkE4igppGnkaWrqKERb6igYmukoGJsY6ygYmVmY6yiYWhqYWMZq/gcA)

> bigomega(x): number of prime divisors of x, counted with multiplicity.

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 14 bytes

```
n->numdiv(n)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y6vNDcls0wjT1PX8H9iQUFOpUaegq6dQkFRZl4JkKkE4igppAEVaOooRFvqKBia6SgYmxjrKBiZWZjrKJhaGphYxmr@BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```
(car(cdr(perfect-power(read))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE5nBpFKUWlmYWpSrkJpZk6OeV5ialFumWZKTmF1Vq/tdITizSSE4p0ihILUpLTS7RLcgvTy0CaklM0QSC//9NLQ1MLAE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 18 bytes

```perl6
{+grep($_%%*,^$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@79aO70otUBDJV5VVUsnTiVes/Z/cSJISsNS05oLyjQ0Q7CNTYwRHCMzC3MEz9TSwASo6z8A)

Anonymous code block that gets a list of factors and coerces it to a number.