# Tips for golfing in Add++

Tags: code-golf, tips

[Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus) is the [Language of the Month for January 2022](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24222/language-of-the-month-for-january-2022-add), and so I'm asking for tips for golfing in it. Please stick to tips specific to Add++, and avoid general tips such as "remove whitespace" or "avoid comments".

Please post separate tips as individual answers

Answer (score 7):

### Use `L` for the main function, `D` for helper functions

Unnamed<sup>*</sup> lambdas have the syntax

```
L<flags>,<code>
```

[For example](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/98nTkfJIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUen//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3UzAQ). This is much shorter than the named version

```
D,<name>,<flags>,<code>
```

For a single byte function name, using a lambda is 3 bytes shorter, and this increases as the name grows longer.

*: Lambdas are stored in the interpreter as functions with the names `lambda 1`, `lambda 2`, etc. so can be accessed this way

If you're submitting a function submission, the main function should always be an unnamed lambda, and any helper functions should be named. Consider,

```
L,€{lambda 2}
L,'
```

vs

```
L,€g
D,g,@,'
```

which saves 5 bytes

Answer (score 7):

### Call your helper functions `I`, `K`, `Y`, `Z`, `g`, `k`, `l`, `u` or `w`

Add++ doesn't have any way to combine multiple functional builtins into one command (for those familiar, like Jelly's `$¥` quicks). If you want to e.g. filter on a complex condition, you'll need to define a helper function containing the code for that condition.

When calling other functions from functional mode, you surround the name with `{...}`:

```
D,main,@,€{triple}
D,triple,@,3*
```

However, if the braces are omitted, it will only take the next character immediately after the quick. In this case, if there's a name clash between a builtin and a user-defined function, the interpreter defaults to the builtin.

So, for this example,

```
D,main,@,€f
D,f,@,5+
```

The `€` will actually call the `f` builtin (prime factors), not the function `f` (add 5).

If the builtin isn't defined however, such as `g`, it will use the function instead. Therefore, you can save 2 bytes per helper function call like

```
D,main,@,€g
D,g,@,5+
```

The undefined builtins are `I`, `K`, `Y`, `Z`, `g`, `k`, `l`, `u` and `w`, so name your helper functions these first, then move onto having to use braces if you have more than 9 helpers

Answer (score 5):

Always use `D` Loop when you use `W` if you want to execute once and go to start of the loop if the condition is 1. This will prevent from duplicating the code.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `&` to swap variables.

This

```
A:1
B:2
; Start of the Swap
C:A
A:B
B:C
; End of the Swap
```

Can be shortened to

```
A:1
B:2
; Start of the Swap
A&B
; End of the Swap
```

(This can be useful if you try to swap in loops)